# Amazon S3: set permissions using aws-sdk-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm getting **Access Denied** for a new images path in S3. This in the same bucket, that I have worked with and for other images everything is fine. Can it be a permissions issue? If so, how can I get (and set) permissions using **aws-sdk-ruby**?

The documentation has poor examples and I don't have access to amazon dashboard.

Can I do these manipulations through the gem anyway?

Comment: did you check your permissions in the aws s3 management console for that bucket?  I know with the gem you can set the acl (access control list) for the given file.  I will post an example below

Comment: I didn't, I don't have access to the console

Comment: Does your key have access to set permissions? If so you might be able to install a desktop app like http://www.3hubapp.com/ and control them

Comment: I also discovered a nice and simple extension to chrome called Extended S3 Browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their docs @ [aws-sdk doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#acl-instance_method)
als you may want to reference the [bucket doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/Bucket.html)

S3 supports a number of canned ACLs for buckets and objects. These include:

```
:private
:public_read
:public_read_write
:authenticated_read
:bucket_owner_read (object-only)
:bucket_owner_full_control (object-only)
:log_delivery_write (bucket-only)
```

Here is an example of providing a canned ACL to a bucket:

```
s3.buckets['bucket-name'].acl = :public_read
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax has changed on

**gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'**

It is now with round brackets, instead of square. 
and in singular

```
s3.bucket(object)
```

instead of

```
s3.buckets[object]
```

**Full-Example :**

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
source = s3.bucket('bucket-name').object('some/path/filename.txt')
destination = s3.bucket('same-or-other-bucket').object('destination/filename2.txt')

copy_to(destination, acl:'public-read')
```

Comment: I havent found how to set the .acl in the new version any ideas_